# No actualiza la vista del componente hijo cuando agrego un elemento desde el padre. Angular

Tags: angular, componentes

Tengo dos componentes el componente padre "experiencia" y el componente hijo "item-experiencia". Desde el componente hijo manejo la vista. Cuando agrego un elemento desde el componente padre la vista del hijo no se actualiza, tengo que recargar la pagina para poder ver los cambios ¿Qué puedo hacer para que el hijo actualice la vista cada vez que se agrega un elemento en el padre?
Mi html en el componente padre:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">{{ titleExperiencia }}</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 contenedor experiencia">
     <app-item-experiencia class="tamañoMedio" >   
     </app-item-experiencia> 
      <div class="container prueba d-none d-lg-block">
        <div class="col-12"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

<!--Modal para agregar el nuevo elemento-->

<div
class="modal fade"
id="staticBackdropAgregar"
data-bs-backdrop="static"
data-bs-keyboard="false"
tabindex="-1"
aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
aria-hidden="true"
>
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">
        Añadir Experiencia
      </h5>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn-close"
        data-bs-dismiss="modal"
        aria-label="Close"
      ></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form class="add-form" [formGroup]="formValue">
        <div class="form-control form-group">
          <label for="experienciaTitulo">Titulo</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            formControlName="experienciaTitulo"
            id="experienciaTitulo"
            placeholder="Editar titulo"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label for="experienciaDescripcion">Descripcion</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            formControlName="experienciaDescripcion"
            id="experienciaDescripcion"
            placeholder="Editar descripcion"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <label for="experienciaLogo">Logo</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            formControlName="experienciaLogo"
            id="experienciaLogo"
            placeholder="Ejemplo bi bi-gear"
          />
          <p>*Admite cualquier icono de Bootstrap</p>
        </div>

        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Añadir"
          class="btn btn-secondary"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          (click)="postExperienciaDetails()"
          (click)="allData()"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

La lógica del componente padre:

```
export class ExperienciaComponent implements OnInit {
  formValue !: FormGroup;
  experienciaModelObj: Experiencia = new Experiencia();
  experienciaData !: any;    
   constructor(   
    private experienciaService: ExperienciaService,   
    private route: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder 
  ) {}
  
  titleExperiencia: string = 'Experiencia';
 
  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.formValue = this.formBuilder.group({
      experienciaTitulo: [''],
      experienciaDescripcion: [''],
      experienciaLogo: ['']
    })
    this.getAllExperiencia();  
   
  }
 
clickAddExperiencia() {
  this.formValue.reset(); 
} 
getAllExperiencia () {
  this.experienciaService.getsExperiencia().subscribe(res => {
 this.experienciaData = res; 
  })
}


postExperienciaDetails(){  
  this.experienciaModelObj.experienciaTitulo = this.formValue.value.experienciaTitulo;
  this.experienciaModelObj.experienciaDescripcion = this.formValue.value.experienciaDescripcion;
  this.experienciaModelObj.experienciaLogo = this.formValue.value.experienciaLogo;   
  this.experienciaService.postExperiencia(this.experienciaModelObj).subscribe(res =>{
    console.log(res);     
    let ref = document.getElementById('cancel')
    ref?.click();
    this.formValue.reset();
    this.getAllExperiencia();  
  })

}
}
```

El html del hijo:

```
<div
  class="list-group experiencia pad"
  *ngFor="let experiencia of experienciaData"
>
  <a    
    class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3"
    aria-current="true"
  >
    <i class="{{ experiencia.experienciaLogo }}" style="font-size: 2em"></i>
    <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
      <div>
        <h6 class="mb-0">
          {{ experiencia.experienciaTitulo }}
        </h6>
        <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">
          {{ experiencia.experienciaDescripcion }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
```

No logro hacer que funcione . Estoy bastante perdido ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Cómo le pasas los datos al hijo?

Comment: Decidí pasar toda a un solo componente y manejarlo desde ahí. No es lo que buscaba y quizá no sea una muy buena practica pero tengo poco tiempo para terminar el proyecto por lo que decidí simplificar al máximo. Gracias de todas maneras.

Comment: me pregunto lo mismo, como pasas los datos?

Comment: Como dice @Lobos una pregunta seria como pasas los datos? pero la forma de obtener los cambios consecutivos segun un evento del padre al hijo es implementando `OnChanges`, y de padre a hijo su comunicacion es atraves de un `@Input()`, como podemos ver que no lo estas usando por que en tu componente padre al implementar el hijo no haces el binding `[datos]="datos"`. Aca te dejo un [ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jrygvf?file=src/app/com-hijo/com-hijo.component.ts) para que puedas entender y la [documentacion](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs) en angular.